# Conditional to compare all values in string

Tags: php, arrays, variables, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a conditional that checks to see if `$variable` is equal to any value in the following string

```
$category_id = "348,349,398,399,400,402,404,406,410,415,417,419,421,423,425,434,436,438,439,442,350,444,446,448,450,458,460,461,464,468,470,475,479,480,481,483,485,487,489,491,492,498,499,501,503,506,352,509,511,513,521,523,533,535,538"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(in_array($searchValue,explode(",",$category_id)))
{
   // in there
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/bbqO0kVM)**